# Cleaner way to filter data

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2018

I have data that is in an array of structs. I don't have access to a query variable, and I need to filter down the data. So var I have

```
    arData = arData.filter(
        function(item){
            return (form.searchPhrase == "" 
                ||
                item.name CONTAINS form.searchPhrase
                ||
                item.company CONTAINS form.searchPhrase
                ||
                item.address CONTAINS form.searchPhrase
                ||
                item.address2 CONTAINS form.searchPhrase
                ||
                item.city CONTAINS form.searchPhrase
                ||
                item.state CONTAINS form.searchPhrase
                ||
                item.zip CONTAINS form.searchPhrase
                ||
                item.email CONTAINS form.searchPhrase
                ||
                item.tel CONTAINS form.searchPhrase
                );
        });
```

I am going over all the fields in item.

What I don't like about this is that it seems highly repetitive. It is likely that a new struct key could be added. Or an existing be removed. I am looking for a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just loop over the item's properties then?

```
arData = arData.filter(
    function(item){
        if (form.searchPhrase == "") {
            return true;
        }
        for (itemProperty in item){
            if (isSimpleValue(item[itemProperty]) && item[itemProperty] CONTAINS form.searchPhrase) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    });
```

In case your item might contain properties with a `null` value (for example if you read JSON from an external API), you want to check `structKeyExists(item, itemProperty)` in the loop as well.